# How can I kill a batch script in execution from another batch script?

Tags: windows, batch, batch-file

I have a .bat file like this:

```
:TOP
Do stuff
GOTO TOP
```

I want to create another .bat file that kills this one gracefully. I don't know what the pid of the process will be ahead of time, and I don't think I can change the process name to allow for an easy kill command. Any ideas?

Comment: maybe the called batch file could find its ppid (parent process id) and kill that.

Comment: Too many ways to skin this cat really as I can think of two right away. Are you able to change the logic of the existing batch script? I see a solution per barlop command and toogam answer.

Comment: @Facebook I should be able to alter the script above

Comment: @Facebook I think that TOOGAM's solution should work for me, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
:top
:: do_stuff
if exist C:\temp\endnow.sig goto aftrloop
goto top
:aftrloop
```

Comment: @Facebook : I suppose after the :aftrloop I could have mentioned ":: do_more_stuff".  Having a "start" file is a sensible addition, but not one I see as necessary for all scenarios, so I just lump that into the category of possible "stuff" that, obviously, can be added if desired.

Comment: Also, I did "consider adding some detail explaining" the logic.  I decided it's really completely straightforward enough that any Batch language programmer will be able to understand it extremely well (if they fully read the question), so for people who don't understand instantly and review this again (to see if they "get it"), in literally two seconds or less they are likely to get the "aha" moment of self-discovery, which will actually clarify things better than extra words that everyone has to read through.  Utilization of KISS was actually an intentional decision.

Comment: So that code is for the child process bat file, and is the ending naturally, when the parent process writes that file to c:\temp.   One would have another bat file(besides that child bat file), the parent bat file, that calls that child bat file. And the parent bat file would at some point say something like `echo asdf>c:\temp\endnow.sig`  It should be noted though that none of this involves really killing a bat file. It's a bat file ending normally but it's equivalent.

Comment: Fair enough, I'm known for trying to make things elaborate but solid from time to time ensuring tasks run without issue. I try to be too proactive and build as such into my automation all the time but I have a few of those quick answers out there too I suppose—I'll find and try to fix or delete perhaps one day. I'm not certain this popped up in review or not—forgot.